# How to add dependency after submitting a proprietary app to USC?

Tags: software-center, application-development, dependencies, packaging

I submitted my app "Brightness Controller" under proprietary license and it has been published. It contains an executable .py file. But the app depends on `python-wxgtk2.8`
I wrote it in the comments field but probably the packagers have ignored it. 
Is there any way I can add the dependency myself?
**Please note that I had not debianized the package. I just tarred the brightness.py file and submitted it.**
Can I just make a .deb with the dependency file and submit it?
*The app is originally [open-source](https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness), but I submitted it under proprietary so that I won't have to package it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before packaging your program, they will check thoroughly all the files, readmes, etc. so the end users won't have problems using your program. The README is explicit enough that it need `python-wxgtk2.8`, also,they most likely will test once it's built.

Ubuntu has strict policies about what packages reach the repositories. It's doubtful that they will miss such big words about the only dependency your software has.

Comment: I just submitted the .py file **(no README)** and indicated the dependency in the comments field. I did not know that they did not add the dependency as I had the package installed already. I read some reviews and came to know the problem. So, should I add a Readme file?

Comment: Would be preferable.

Comment: It's not necessary, it will be found during the package creation. The best way to address is to add "feedback" to your application submission.

Comment: @zoopster I believe that he's receiving bug reports from the users **after** the package was sent and done. The package team failed to see comments in the package submission form, hence now he has a non-working package.

Answer (score 2):

What ?? Thats not the correct way to publish an application to Ubuntu Software center actually as i have submitted more then 15 applicatons both free and non-free, i made a video tutorial with all the setup you need to do to package an application and upload it to any store.

First of all they wont accept source code of your application. Cause that makes it opensource !! They accept a debianized archive. the process of debianizing the app is also covered in my youtube video. after that you upload the debianized tar.gz to store. read the official docs in ubuntu site or watch the video to learn how you do that .

- Video covers create a basic webcam application in qt.
- Packaging it in Debian format.
- Calculating dependencies for application
- Upload it to Ubuntu-Play-Store.

Note- You will need to upload the tar.gz you get after the debian packaging if you upload it to ubuntu software center.

here is the youtube link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be3vRVqPt58